# ng-repeat ng-init variable gets out of sync.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat method to list some stuff out.  There is a nested ng-repeat so I'm using ng-init to track my outer $index.

```
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="product in products" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" ng-init="current = $index">

        <div class="col col-50" ng-repeat="idx in [0,1]" ng-if="(current + idx) < products.length">
          <div class="item-product" ui-sref="^.product({productId: products[current + idx].Id})">

              <div ng-if="products[current + idx].image">
                <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{ products[current + idx].image }}">
              </div>

              <p class="ellipsis"><b>{{ current + idx }}  {{ products[current + idx].Name }}</b><br/>

              <span ng-if="products[current + idx].Description" class="ellipsis">{{ products[current + idx].Description }}</span></p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This works fine most of the time.  But there are situations where current gets out of sync.  If I set a certain filter I end up with 12 products.  When I dump out $index and current side by side per row I get the following.

```
0 - 0
2 - 6
4 - 12
6 - 18
8 - 24
10 - 30
```

For some reason my current starts jumping by 6.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Looks like the ng-init is being incremented for every even index.

Comment: What kind of filter are you setting? And could you perhaps upload a jsfiddle that demonstrates the behaviour?

Comment: Each filter is just a scope variable and the products array is filtered when one changes, the $scope.products is set to the new filtered set.  The filtering is working correctly and if I output the products I get the correct ones.  The weird thing is this only happens the first time.  After that it's fine.  When I change a different filter I get a random jump of 20 in current but other than that it increments by 2 as expected.

Comment: The problem seems to be the first time I change $scope.products current and $index get out of sync.  After that they get back in sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider tracking the `ng-repeat` by index to simplify things:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products track by $index"></div>
```